# NGINX compile and gzip config (with rails 3 + php-fpm): "can't unzip" by torrent client from php tracker

Tags: php, nginx, gzip, tracker, utorrent

Hi there: I have got a weird question about a new server installed with Nginx+php-fpm+passenger. Everything is the latest version. I have got everything configured well, all the web pages are running, however when the users tried to access the php tracker of my private tracker, it returns them an error: "can't unzip". This is uTorrent. On Vuze it is a Java Gzip exception saying it's not a valid gzip file or so, which clearly shows that the server has been returning some gzip data the clients don't understand.

So here's my nginx.conf:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /home/meng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /home/meng/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_static  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The nginx was compiled by passenger with the arguments of:
--with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_gzip_static_module
based on the tutorial stated here 
http://geeksharp.com/2010/09/14/nginx-rails-and-php-round-2/
So I guess this is a gzip problem, anyone have any solutions to get the server return the correct gzip data, so the clients eat it? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off gzip_static for your dynamically generated locations. gzip_static will try to create a .gz file in the same directory as the request, and this may cause issues with PHP, Ruby, etc.

Also, I'd turn up gzip_comp_level to 5 or 6, especially if you are caching the compressed file with gzip_static.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem seems solved by turning down the error reporting level of php since it's pumping errors like deprecated or notice prior to the proper gzip data. The program works fine after turning it off. I will turn the gzip level to what you said. ~

Comment: There's a setting in php.ini called display_errors which you can use to disable the errors on a production box.